# How to calculate number of days per month between multiple periods and with criteria for calendar/working days?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have two types of workers (shift and non-shift).  Shift workers have vacation in calendar days and non-shift in working days.  I need to calculate the number of days between the four periods in a roster for workers who may be shift or non-shift.  The formula I used to get working days in any given month is

```
=IF(ISBLANK(X2),0,IF(ISBLANK($AD2),IF(ISBLANK($AB2),
  IF(ISBLANK($Z2),(MAX(0,NETWORKDAYS.INTL(MAX(AF$1,$X2),
  MIN(EOMONTH(AF$1,0),$Y2),1,Holidays))),(MAX(0,NETWORKDAYS.INTL(MAX(AF$1,$X2),
  MIN(EOMONTH(AF$1,0),$Y2),1,Holidays)))+(MAX(0,NETWORKDAYS.INTL(MAX(AF$1,$Z2),
  MIN(EOMONTH(AF$1,0),$AA2),1,Holidays)))),(MAX(0,NETWORKDAYS.INTL(MAX(AF$1,$X2),
  MIN(EOMONTH(AF$1,0),$Y2),1,Holidays)))+(MAX(0,NETWORKDAYS.INTL(MAX(AF$1,$Z2),
  MIN(EOMONTH(AF$1,0),$AA2),1,Holidays)))+(MAX(0,NETWORKDAYS.INTL(MAX(AF$1,$AB2),
  MIN(EOMONTH(AF$1,0),$AC2),1,Holidays)))),(MAX(0,NETWORKDAYS.INTL(MAX(AF$1,$X2),
  MIN(EOMONTH(AF$1,0),$Y2),1,Holidays)))+(MAX(0,NETWORKDAYS.INTL(MAX(AF$1,$Z2),
  MIN(EOMONTH(AF$1,0),$AA2),1,Holidays)))+(MAX(0,NETWORKDAYS.INTL(MAX(AF$1,$AB2),
  MIN(EOMONTH(AF$1,0),$AC2),1,Holidays)))+(MAX(0,NETWORKDAYS.INTL(MAX(AF$1,$AD2),
  MIN(EOMONTH(AF$1,0),$AE2),1,Holidays)))))
```

where start dates and end dates of the four periods are X2-Y2, Z2-AA2, AB2-AC2 and AD2-AE2.  Not all workers will schedule leave in four periods. Holidays refers to a table that identifies all the holidays in the year.

|  | W | X | Y | Z | AA | AB | AC | AD | AE | AF | AG | AH | AI | AJ | AK | AL | AM | AN | AO | AP | AQ | AR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | Unit | Start Date (1st Period) yyyy-mm-dd | End Date (1st Period) yyyy-mm-dd | Start Date (2nd Period) yyyy-mm-dd | End Date (2nd Period) yyyy-mm-dd | Start Date (3rd Period) yyyy-mm-dd | End Date (3rd Period) yyyy-mm-dd | Start Date (4th Period) yyyy-mm-dd | End Date (4th Period)yyyy-mm-dd | 24-Jan | 24-Feb | 24-Mar | 24-Apr | 24-May | 24-Jun | 24-Jul | 24-Aug | 24-Sep | 24-Oct | 24-Nov | 24-Dec | TOTAL SCHEDULE DAYS |
| **2** | No Shift | 2024-01-01 | 2024-01-09 | 2024-02-26 | 2024-02-28 | 2024-03-01 | 2024-05-01 | 2024-09-01 | 2024-09-30 | 29 | 2 | 30 | 29 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 29 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 29 |
| **3** | No Shift | 2024-03-05 | 2024-06-11 | 2024-07-01 | 2024-07-13 | 2024-09-15 | 2024-09-30 | 2024-11-15 | 2024-11-30 | 15 | 0 | 26 | 29 | 30 | 10 | 12 | 0 | 15 | 0 | 11 | 0 | 26 |
| **4** | Shift | 2024-01-15 | 2024-03-23 | 2024-05-05 | 2024-09-11 |  |  |  |  | 10 | 28 | 22 | 0 | 26 | 29 | 30 | 30 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 10 |
| **5** | No Shift | 2024-05-05 | 2024-09-11 | 2024-11-15 | 2024-11-30 |  |  |  |  | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 26 | 29 | 30 | 30 | 10 | 0 | 11 | 0 | 21 |
| **6** | No Shift | 2024-05-05 | 2024-06-18 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 25 | 17 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| **7** | Shift | 2024-05-05 | 2024-09-11 |  |  |  |  |  |  | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 25 | 29 | 29 | 29 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 10 |

| 01/01/2024 | New Year's Day |
| --- | --- |
| 30/03/2024 | Spiritual Baptist/Shouter Liberation Day |
| 29/03/2024 | Good Friday |
| 01/04/2024 | Easter Monday |
| 09/04/2024 | Eid |
| 31/05/2024 | Indian Arrival Day |
| 30/05/2024 | Corpus Christi |
| 19/06/2024 | Labour Day |
| 01/08/2024 | Emancipation Day |
| 31/08/2024 | Independence Day |
| 24/09/2024 | Republic Day |
| 30/11/2024 | Divali |
| 25/12/2024 | Christmas Day |
| 26/12/2024 | Boxing Day |
| 01/01/2025 | New Year's Day |

This formula is long and I have yet to include an IF formula depending on the type of worker.  Does anyone have any ideas to assist with this?

If a shift worker takes leave from 2024-01-01 to 2024-01-31, the number of days should be 30 under the month of January whereas the non-shift worker will have only working days counted - 22 days. Also any holidays within the period must be subtracted.

I tried to incorporate a WORKDAY.INTL function for the shift worker whose days have to be calculated in calendar days but that yielded a serial number and not the number of days.

Comment: Please include some sample data into your question, including expected output with that data. You could use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables to post your data as a table in your question.

Comment: I included sample data as you suggested

Comment: Think about structure: you test 4 cells individually for blank - test all 4 in one go. Then think about the rest of the structure.

Comment: Thanks for adding the sample data; that's a start. So with given data, what do you expect as output and where/why? Don't we need a sample holidays table to reproduce?

Comment: I included the table with the holidays.  Ideally I would want the formula to ensure that there is no overlap with periods in instances where there is more than 1 period of vacation but I am not sure how to incorporate that.

Comment: @SolarMike I tested the blanks individually because individuals may not necessarily use all four periods, some may take 1, others 2 or 3 or 4.  Can you suggest a formula that would enable the calculation to work in such a way?  Before incorporating the ISBLANK function, the formula would evaluate 22/21/20 days instead of 0 days in those months for which no vacation period applies.

Comment: The expected output goes in columns AF to AQ, which shows the 12 months of the year. If a non-shift person takes vacation from 15 January to 23 March 2024,  Jan should show 13, Feb 20 and March 16.  A shift person taking the same period would have Jan 16, Feb 28 and March 23.

Comment: To get things clear: So columns `X:AE` contain the scheduled holiday periods (start to end of period) and you want to count the number of working days it "costs" for given month in column `AF:AQ`, excluding holidays, and only in case of a shift employee excluding weekends as well?  Do I summarize that correctly? Is column `AR` used in a way?

Comment: Yes @Pb. AR is just the sum of the 12 months.

Comment: Note that the shift emp has calendar days as the count and non shift has weekdays for their working days

Comment: Why 19 days for the non shift workers taking holidays from 1/1 to 31/1? Shouldn't that be 22 days?

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey yes 22 days for the non shift worker for the entire month of January

Comment: Do holidays count for leave time for shift workers?

Comment: Usually they don't @RonRosenfeld but for the purposes of disguising the true fields of my data, I used shift and non shift. I really do have two categories of workers, one whose work conditions are calendar days and the other weekdays.

Comment: **Usually**?? So sometimes they do count for shift workers and sometimes they do not? How is the formula supposed to determine that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood things right:

I wrapped the row in column `X:AE` into two columns, where the first column are the start dates and the second the end dates of the period and called it `startend`.

Next I used REDUCE to stack the sequences of dates from the start to the end date of each "row" from the `startend` array and name it `days`.

I filtered out the days from the `days` array that match the `holidays` range and name this `netdays`.

Next I filter out only days from the `netdays` array where the month equals the month of the header values and if the line shows `shift` in column `W` I keep the weekends, else I exclude the weekends *(`MOD(netdays,7)>1` where Saturday and Sunday return `0` and `1` as a result of the MOD).*

Paste this in `AF2` and drag down:

```
=LET(startend,WRAPROWS(TOROW($X2:$AE2,1),2),
     days,DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(startend)),LAMBDA(x,y,LET(s,INDEX(startend,y,1),e,INDEX(startend,y,2)+1,VSTACK(x,SEQUENCE(e-s,,s))))),1),
     netdays,TOCOL(days/ISERROR(XMATCH(days,Holidays)),2),
BYCOL(AF$1:AQ$1,LAMBDA(m,COUNT(FILTER(netdays,(MONTH(netdays)=MONTH(m))*IF($W2="Shift",1,MOD(netdays,7)>1),"")))))
```

[image]

PS `AR2` is a simple `=SUM(AF2#)` dragged down.

You could also include it like:

```
=LET(startend,WRAPROWS(TOROW($X2:$AE2,1),2),
     days,DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(startend)),LAMBDA(x,y,LET(s,INDEX(startend,y,1),e,INDEX(startend,y,2)+1,VSTACK(x,SEQUENCE(e-s,,s))))),1),
     netdays,TOCOL(days/ISERROR(XMATCH(days,Holidays)),2),
     monthly,BYCOL(AF$1:AQ$1,LAMBDA(m,COUNT(FILTER(netdays,(MONTH(netdays)=MONTH(m))*IF($W2="Shift",1,MOD(netdays,7)>1),"")))),
HSTACK(monthly,SUM(monthly)))
```

Comment: I will let you know if this works tomorrow

Comment: Nice formula solution. I was working on a PQ solution. But I don't understand your last column (AQ). Shouldn't that be the sum of the previous twelve?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld that last `AQ` is actually still the values I copied from the example. Didn't work on that and didn't remove them.

Comment: Mind that the original table is placed one more column to the right. So the formula (proprerly edited) is to be placed in AF2, not in AE2.

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey Good catch; I know what happened there. I included a column prior to the shift column for the purpose of pasting the data including columns and row numbers in the question. After that I deleted that row counter column and that shifted the whole data one column. I decided to edit my answer to match the data as originally intended.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I also decided to edit in the sum of the calculation because we can, because I was editing anyway and because it was showing wrong info in my original answer and I can see that raising questions.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly! thanks for the solution Pb

Answer (score 0):

Create a new sheet named Holidays and past these into it:

|  |  |  |  | No shift | Shift |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Date | Anniversary |  | Non-working days | 67 |  |
| 45292 | New Year's Day |  |  |  |  |
| 45381 | Spiritual Baptist/Shouter Liberation Day |  | 45292 | =IF(OR(IFERROR(SEARCH(WEEKDAY($D5,2),E$3),FALSE),COUNTIF(A:A,$D5)),0,1) | =IF(OR(IFERROR(SEARCH(WEEKDAY($D5,2),F$3),FALSE),COUNTIF($A:$A,$D5)),0,1) |
| 45380 | Good Friday |  | =IF(YEAR(D5+1)>YEAR(D5),"",D5+1) | =IF(OR(IFERROR(SEARCH(WEEKDAY($D6,2),E$3),FALSE),COUNTIF(A:A,$D6)>0),0,1) | =IF(OR(IFERROR(SEARCH(WEEKDAY($D6,2),F$3),FALSE),COUNTIF($A:$A,$D6)>0),0,1) |
| 45383 | Easter Monday |  |  |  |  |
| 45391 | Eid |  |  |  |  |
| 45443 | Indian Arrival Day |  |  |  |  |
| 45442 | Corpus Christi |  |  |  |  |
| 45462 | Labour Day |  |  |  |  |
| 45505 | Emancipation Day |  |  |  |  |
| 45535 | Independence Day |  |  |  |  |
| 45559 | Republic Day |  |  |  |  |
| 45626 | Divali |  |  |  |  |
| 45651 | Christmas Day |  |  |  |  |
| 45652 | Boxing Day |  |  |  |  |
| 45658 | New Year's Day |  |  |  |  |

Drag down range D6:F6 to row 370. This way it will cover the whole year. By changing the date in cell D5, the whole year will change. By adding or removing dates in the table in columns A and B, you will add or remove anniversary that will be counted as holidays in the given year for all kind of workers. You can also add new kind of workers: right now you have No shift workers in column E and Shift workers in column F. As you can see, their kind's name is reported in row 1. In row 3 you can specify what days of the week must be counted as non working days: no shift workers don't work during saturdays and sundays therefore in cell E3 the digits 6 and 7 are reported; shift workers don't have any regular non-working day so no digit is reported (therefore only anniversaries will be considered non-working days).

In your table you can paste this:

| W | X | Y | Z | AA | AB | AC | AD | AE | AF | AG | AH | AI | AJ | AK | AL | AM | AN | AO | AP | AQ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Unit | Start Date (1st Period) yyyy-mm-dd | End Date (1st Period) yyyy-mm-dd | Start Date (2nd Period) yyyy-mm-dd | End Date (2nd Period) yyyy-mm-dd | Start Date (3rd Period) yyyy-mm-dd | End Date (3rd Period) yyyy-mm-dd | Start Date (4th Period) yyyy-mm-dd | End Date (4th Period)yyyy-mm-dd | =DATE(YEAR(Holidays!$D$5),COLUMNS($AF$1:AF1)+1,1)-1 | =DATE(YEAR(Holidays!$D$5),COLUMNS($AF$1:AG1)+1,1)-1 | =DATE(YEAR(Holidays!$D$5),COLUMNS($AF$1:AH1)+1,1)-1 | =DATE(YEAR(Holidays!$D$5),COLUMNS($AF$1:AI1)+1,1)-1 | =DATE(YEAR(Holidays!$D$5),COLUMNS($AF$1:AJ1)+1,1)-1 | =DATE(YEAR(Holidays!$D$5),COLUMNS($AF$1:AK1)+1,1)-1 | =DATE(YEAR(Holidays!$D$5),COLUMNS($AF$1:AL1)+1,1)-1 | =DATE(YEAR(Holidays!$D$5),COLUMNS($AF$1:AM1)+1,1)-1 | =DATE(YEAR(Holidays!$D$5),COLUMNS($AF$1:AN1)+1,1)-1 | =DATE(YEAR(Holidays!$D$5),COLUMNS($AF$1:AO1)+1,1)-1 | =DATE(YEAR(Holidays!$D$5),COLUMNS($AF$1:AP1)+1,1)-1 | =DATE(YEAR(Holidays!$D$5),COLUMNS($AF$1:AQ1)+1,1)-1 |
| no shift | 45292 | 45300 | 45348 | 45350 | 45352 | 45413 | 45536 | 45565 | =SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$X2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$Y2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AF$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AF$1)-1,12,31),AE$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AF$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$Z2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AA2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AF$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AF$1)-1,12,31),AE$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AF$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AB2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AC2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AF$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AF$1)-1,12,31),AE$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AF$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AD2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AE2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AF$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AF$1)-1,12,31),AE$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AF$1) | =SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$X2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$Y2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AG$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AG$1)-1,12,31),AF$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AG$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$Z2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AA2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AG$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AG$1)-1,12,31),AF$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AG$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AB2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AC2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AG$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AG$1)-1,12,31),AF$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AG$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AD2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AE2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AG$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AG$1)-1,12,31),AF$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AG$1) | =SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$X2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$Y2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AH$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AH$1)-1,12,31),AG$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AH$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$Z2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AA2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AH$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AH$1)-1,12,31),AG$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AH$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AB2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AC2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AH$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AH$1)-1,12,31),AG$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AH$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AD2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AE2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AH$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AH$1)-1,12,31),AG$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AH$1) | =SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$X2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$Y2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AI$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AI$1)-1,12,31),AH$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AI$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$Z2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AA2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AI$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AI$1)-1,12,31),AH$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AI$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AB2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AC2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AI$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AI$1)-1,12,31),AH$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AI$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AD2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AE2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AI$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AI$1)-1,12,31),AH$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AI$1) | =SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$X2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$Y2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AJ$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AJ$1)-1,12,31),AI$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AJ$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$Z2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AA2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AJ$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AJ$1)-1,12,31),AI$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AJ$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AB2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AC2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AJ$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AJ$1)-1,12,31),AI$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AJ$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AD2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AE2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AJ$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AJ$1)-1,12,31),AI$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AJ$1) | =SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$X2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$Y2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AK$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AK$1)-1,12,31),AJ$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AK$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$Z2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AA2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AK$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AK$1)-1,12,31),AJ$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AK$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AB2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AC2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AK$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AK$1)-1,12,31),AJ$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AK$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AD2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AE2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AK$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AK$1)-1,12,31),AJ$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AK$1) | =SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$X2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$Y2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AL$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AL$1)-1,12,31),AK$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AL$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$Z2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AA2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AL$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AL$1)-1,12,31),AK$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AL$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AB2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AC2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AL$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AL$1)-1,12,31),AK$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AL$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AD2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AE2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AL$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AL$1)-1,12,31),AK$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AL$1) | =SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$X2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$Y2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AM$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AM$1)-1,12,31),AL$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AM$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$Z2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AA2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AM$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AM$1)-1,12,31),AL$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AM$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AB2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AC2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AM$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AM$1)-1,12,31),AL$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AM$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AD2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AE2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AM$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AM$1)-1,12,31),AL$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AM$1) | =SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$X2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$Y2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AN$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AN$1)-1,12,31),AM$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AN$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$Z2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AA2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AN$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AN$1)-1,12,31),AM$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AN$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AB2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AC2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AN$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AN$1)-1,12,31),AM$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AN$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AD2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AE2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AN$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AN$1)-1,12,31),AM$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AN$1) | =SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$X2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$Y2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AO$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AO$1)-1,12,31),AN$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AO$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$Z2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AA2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AO$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AO$1)-1,12,31),AN$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AO$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AB2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AC2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AO$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AO$1)-1,12,31),AN$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AO$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AD2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AE2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AO$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AO$1)-1,12,31),AN$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AO$1) | =SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$X2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$Y2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AP$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AP$1)-1,12,31),AO$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AP$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$Z2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AA2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AP$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AP$1)-1,12,31),AO$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AP$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AB2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AC2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AP$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AP$1)-1,12,31),AO$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AP$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AD2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AE2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AP$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AP$1)-1,12,31),AO$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AP$1) | =SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$X2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$Y2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AQ$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AQ$1)-1,12,31),AP$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AQ$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$Z2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AA2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AQ$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AQ$1)-1,12,31),AP$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AQ$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AB2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AC2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AQ$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AQ$1)-1,12,31),AP$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AQ$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AD2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AE2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AQ$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AQ$1)-1,12,31),AP$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AQ$1) |

You can drag down range AF2:AQ2.

#### FORMULAS ANALISYS

---

Address: Holidays!D5

```
=IF(YEAR(D5+1)>YEAR(D5),"",D5+1)
```

This formula is meant to reproduce each days of a given year but the first one (which will be stored in cell Holidays!D4). At its core it simply adds a new day to the one reported in the row above. Since a year can't have more than 366 days, the formula need to be placed in 365 cells (therefore in the range D5:D370). If the given year is not a leap year, in cell D370 we could expect the first day of the new year to be reported. The formula checks the year of the date in the previous row and the one of its next day and if they are not the same nothing will be reported. By changing the date in cell Holidays!D4, one can easily have the whole year displayed.

---

Address: Holidays!E5

```
=IF(OR(IFERROR(SEARCH(WEEKDAY($D5,2),E$3),FALSE),COUNTIF(A:A,$D5)),0,1)
```

We need to fill this column with either 1s or 0s. Based on the given day in range Holidays!D4:D370, a 1 must be reported if it's a working day (therefore to be counted) while a 0 will signify a non-working day. This way we will be able to sum the values contained in any proper range corrisponding to the given dates. We have 2 main reason to count a day as non working one: anniversaries and weekly rest days. Anniversaries are listed in column Holidays!A:A and are assumed to affect any kind of worker. Weekly rest days can vary, therefore we have to specify them. For this task we can use row 3. There are only 7 days in a week, therefore each digit we will specify in cell E3 will correspond to a single day. Using the WEEKDAY function we can determine what day of the week we are analysing. Using the SEARCH function we can determine whether in cell E3 the give day has been specified: if that's the case, the SEARCH function will return a number (its position in the string); if there is no match, the SEARCH function will return an error. Using the IFERROR function we can force this part of the formula to either return a number (that, being not a 0, will be interpreted as a TRUE) or to return a FALSE. This part of the formula take cares of weekly rest days. We can then nest this part of the formula into a OR function. In this OR function we shall nest also the part dedicated to the anniversaries. A simple COUNTIF function will count any occurence of the day we are analysing in the anniversary list, returning a 0 (that will be interpreted as a FALSE) if the given day is not in the list or a number grater than 0 (that will be interpreted as a TRUE) if the given day is in the list. This OR function will be therefore nested in a simple IF function to return 0 or 1 accordingly to our task.

---

Address: Holidays!F5

```
=IF(OR(IFERROR(SEARCH(WEEKDAY($D5,2),F$3),FALSE),COUNTIF($A:$A,$D5)),0,1)
```

This formula is basically the same as the one in Holidays!E5. Some of its reference are just offset in order to evaluate a new kind of worker. This time the cell F3 will report the weekly rest days while in cell F1 we have the name of the type of worker. One can add as many kind of worker as needed. Just specify the kind's name in row 1, the weekly rest days in row 3 and copy the formulas of rows 5:370.

---

Address: Main!AF1

```
=DATE(YEAR(Holidays!$D$5),COLUMNS($AF$1:AF1)+1,1)-1
```

This formula (dragged in range Main!AF1:AQ1) return the last day of the given month of the given year. The YEAR function will return the year of the date stored in Holidays!$D$5. The COLUMNS function will return a increasing series of value (starting from cell AF1) to which we will add 1 in order to obtain the "next month serial number". A 1 will specify the day. Since each months have a specific number of days while they all start with their first day, the DATE function will pick the first day of the next month; to this day which we will subtract 1 in order to obtain the last day of the given month.

---

Address: Main!AF2

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$X2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$Y2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AF$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AF$1)-1,12,31),AE$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AF$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$Z2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AA2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AF$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AF$1)-1,12,31),AE$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AF$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AB2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AC2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AF$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AF$1)-1,12,31),AE$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AF$1)+SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$AD2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$AE2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AF$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AF$1)-1,12,31),AE$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AF$1)
```

This long formula is simply a long stream of 4 SUMIFS all added togheter. Each SUMIFS refers to one of the periods in the given row of range Main!X:AE. We can focus on the first period to ease our analysis.

```
SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Holidays!C"&MATCH($W2,Holidays!$1:$1,0),FALSE),Holidays!$D:$D,">="&$X2,Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&$Y2,Holidays!$D:$D,">"&IF(MONTH(AF$1)=1,DATE(YEAR(AF$1)-1,12,31),AE$1),Holidays!$D:$D,"<="&AF$1)
```

The first part of a SUMIFS function is the sum range. Depending on the kind of worker we are focusing on (as specified in the given cell of column W), we will use a MATCH function to find in what column of the Holiday sheet is stored the range we are looking for. A INDIRECT function will finalize the range address. The next part of the SUMIFS function is the criteria range. No matter what criteria we are using, in this formula every criteria range will be Holidays!$D:$D, the range where all the days of our year are specified. Now we have to specify the criterias. The first one will deal with all the days equals or "greater" than the starting day specified in the given cell of column X. The second criteria will deal with all the days equals or "lesser" than the ending day specified in the given cell of colum Y. The third criteria will deal with all the days "greater" than the day specified in the cell in the first row of the previous column (in this case cell AE1); but since cell AF1 is the first date of the headers, cell AE1 will not contain a date; we will need an IF function to check if we are operating in the column AF and, in such case, we will have to recreate the first day of the given year. The fourth criteria will deal with all the days equal or "lesser" than the day specified in the cell in the first row of the given column (in this case cell AF1).
This first SUMIFS function is then added to its alikes tuned to focus on all the other periods. This way the formula will return the sum of all days in each period for the given month. Dragging to the right this formula to cover the range AF1:AQ1 and then dragging said range down as needed will return the data we were looking for.

Comment: I will experiment with this in a while - love to learn new things :)

Comment: Being so i might add some explanation. Tell me if you have any question.

Comment: Explanations added.